# How to Rewrite example.com/index.cfm/some-text/some-more-text/ to example.com/some-text/some-more-text/ IIS web.config

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

I need to remove `index.cfm` in my url. I'm using below code. it works to remove `index.cfm` from last of url like `.com/index.cfm` is resolving to `.com/` but not anything after `index.cfm`.

**CODE I'm Using**

```
 <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)index.cfm" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^.*(/index.cfm/).*$" negate="true" />

        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```